# Include Google Maps in loop to show several maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, loops

I have a Rails 5 application where I want to display several Google Maps maps inside a loop. For every row in the table, the same map has to appear. However, the map is only drawn once:

[image: All 3 rows should have the image]

Here is the view:

```
thead
  tr
    th Map
    th Title
    th Distance
    th Duration
    th Sport
tbody
  - @feed.each do |item|
    tr
      td.col-md-3
        #stravaMap
      td.col-md-2
        = Date.parse(item['start_date'])
      td.col-md-2
        = item['name']
      td.col-md-1
        = item['distance'] / 1000
      td.col-md-1
        = item['type']
```

And here is the JS:

```
javascript:
  function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('stravaMap'), {
      center: {
          lat: 47.20604,
          lng: 7.53621
      },
      zoom: 16,
      disableDefaultUI: true
  });

  var encoded_data = 'k|b_Hc|~l@UI';

  var decode = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_data);

  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: decode,
      strokeColor: '#00008B',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 4,
      zIndex: 3
  });

  line.setMap(map);
}

initMap();
```

My understanding is that a new map would be drawn everytime I loop through but it's drawn once and then doesn't appear after first loop.

Question: How do I make sure the Google Maps map is included in every row and not just the first? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As Gabe alluded to above, this part of your code: `document.getElementById('stravaMap')`, will only grab the first element in the DOM that has the id `stravaMap`. If you want to grab all the elements in the DOM where you want to display a Map, then I suggest using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll). This will give you what is essentially an Array of all the elements with a certain class. You can then iterate over that array of elements, initialising a new Map for each element (each `td.map` in your case). I had a quick go at it here:

```
function initMap() {
  mapElements = document.querySelectorAll('.map')

  mapElements.forEach((element) => {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(element, {
      center: {
          lat: 47.20604,
          lng: 7.53621
      },
      zoom: 16,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    });

    var encoded_data = 'k|b_Hc|~l@UI';

    var decode = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(encoded_data);

    var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: decode,
      strokeColor: '#00008B',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 4,
      zIndex: 3
    });

    line.setMap(map);
  }  
})

initMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are creating elements with duplicate `id` attributes this could cause issues with your `document.getElementById('stravaMap')` call.

I'm not sure if you could use a class to get the map in all elements otherwise you could add a custom id for each entry and then loop through them in the javascript to add to each individual run entry.

Comment: Cheers mate. That was the last thing I tried before going to bed last night. I can use document.getElementsByClassName('stravaMap') but it requires me to do [0] or [1] after the call to specify which row it should appear. I'm not experienced with JS - could you possibly show me how such a loop would look like? Be happy to pay for your trouble.